# How to get(or train comprehend) category of document in AWS comprehend

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-comprehend

I want to get the category of the document from the corpus of the document.

categories like brochure, catalogue, certificate, Resume

Is there any way to do it? or how can I train the AWS comprehend to identify the category of a document?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option of custom classifier in comprehend where you need to prepare the simple csv file with training data to train the service according to your data.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/comprehend/latest/dg/how-document-classification.html